# Contextual Links Call to undefined function user_access

Tags: views, navigation, users

I am trying to import my drupal site into Acquia Dev Desktop and keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `user_access()` in */Users/brendan/Sites/homedir/public_html/hewinsfinancial/modules/contextual/contextual.module* on line 86

```
function contextual_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Nothing to do here if the user is not permitted to access contextual links.
  if (!user_access('access contextual links')) {
    return;
  }

  $hooks = theme_get_registry(FALSE);

  // Determine the primary theme function argument.
  if (!empty($hooks[$hook]['variables'])) {
    $keys = array_keys($hooks[$hook]['variables']);
    $key = $keys[0];
  }
  elseif (!empty($hooks[$hook]['render element'])) {
    $key = $hooks[$hook]['render element'];
  }
  if (!empty($key) && isset($variables[$key])) {
    $element = $variables[$key];
  }

  if (isset($element) && is_array($element) && !empty($element['#contextual_links'])) {
    // Initialize the template variable as a renderable array.
    $variables['title_suffix']['contextual_links'] = array(
      '#type' => 'contextual_links',
      '#contextual_links' => $element['#contextual_links'],
      '#element' => $element,
    );
    // Mark this element as potentially having contextual links attached to it.
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'contextual-links-region';
  }
}
```

Comment: You sated a fact. If all you wanted was to report bug, you should do it in Acquia's issue queue, not here. If you want to get answers, please ask questions. Oh, and I formatted it a bit for you, don't break it doing your edits, OK?